# ASP.NET MVC 2: getting model data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I understand how to get the Model Data using a `foreach` loop:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.Deal) { %>
```

Then you'd say:

```
<%: item.DealValue %>
```

But how do I get information about the first result without being in the loop? Like:

```
<%: Model.Deal.DealValue %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your will probably have to pass in an IList instead of an IEnumerable. Something like:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<System.Collections.Generic.IList<Entity>>"
```

Then seems reasonable that you should have access to the array via indices.

Comment: Can I still loop an IList like I am?

Comment: Just tried this in one of my views and I am able to do something like <%= Model[0].XXX %> to access the XXX property.

Comment: that's what I was lookin' for. `Model.Deal[0].DealValue`